# QuickTime - Record internal audio and not external audio

Tags: quicktime, recording, screen-recording

My goal is to record my screen with internal audio, but leaving out external audio. I tried [solutions with Soundflower software](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNYZOaf3Gvs), and it works for the first part.

I cannot mute my external audio. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Click the link under the video for the newer version.

Comment: Not sure I see the same videos you see. Do you mean [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jCLA5xJP9Ms)? If so, I don't think it solves my problem. Am I wrong?

Comment: I have no clue where you got that link from. Directly below your video it says "I made another version of this video that works for newer Mac system, make sure to check it out: https://youtu.be/K7UE8fZjox4 " I haven't watched either one. I don't feel the need to ever watch someone waffling for 6 minutes with information I could have read in one.

Comment: What is "external audio" exactly?  Are you trying to record something like a Zoom session where everyone is talking and you want to leave your voice out?  Showing us tutorials isn't helpful.  Please describe what *you* want to do.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, I'm sorry if I was not enough clear.

Comment: If your voice is *sent* to the Zoom app, which it is, because the other participants need to hear you, then you can't mute it after the fact. In other words, your voice becomes part of the whole Zoom audio stream - this is like trying to remove a single voice from a chorus that was recorded with only one microphone.  You have to contro/capture *all* the voices prior to sending to Zoom then record everything separately while Zoom is muted.

Answer (score 2):

There is a shareware/free software designed specifically for this task called **BlackHole** which I use on a weekly basis.  [Here](https://existential.audio/blackhole/) is the developer's website and [here](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) is his project on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not clear if you want a good tool that lets you choose which audio gets recorded or a tool to make a patch panel to change audio routing.

For either of these “good general purpose tools”, I’m a fan of

- https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/
- http://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm

Based in how you define internal and external audio, a free or less expensive tool than Loopback might work for some basic setups.

Comment: My bad. My goal is to record internal audio (like a meet or a video) without recording the external audio (my voice). Is it possible?